# React-360: Use external Image as Scene Background

Tags: web, virtual-reality, react-360

i have been trying for some time to set an external image over the environment.
This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    asset,
    View,
    VrButton,
} from 'react-360';

import {Environment} from 'react-360';

// Set the background to a 360 or 180 image
Environment.setBackgroundImage(
    {uri: 'https://devcdn.player360.de/dev/media-768-raw.jpg'}
    // asset('media-768-raw.jpg')
);

export default class Hello360 extends React.Component {
    // Our component will keep track of this state
    state = {
    };


    componentDidMount(){
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.panel}>
                <Text>
                    <Text>Hey</Text>
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    panel: {
        // Fill the entire surface
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hello360', () => Hello360);
```

React seems to try to load the image but it simply cancled for some reason.

[Developer Tools: Network Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToHG9.png)

Also the console output gives no indication of a CORS or any other exception:

[Console Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCnW4.png)

The background of my scene is still black. What would be the correct way to include dynamically external images in react-360?

Comment: Maybe someone could create the tag react-360? It requires 1500 rep points, which i don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was still the right way to load external images.

The problem was, that a filter was active in my console output. Therefore I was not able to see the CORS warning in the console.

It was still a CORS problem on the devcdn.player360.de server. We fixed the CORS headers and are now able to load external images.